# List of resources for Windows 8 Metro on writing apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I see a lot of C#/XAML resources out there, but I'm wondering if there are any resources for HTML/CSS/JavaScript version on writing Windows 8 Metro apps?

By resources, I mean any of these:

- tutorials
- lessons
- sessions
- videos
- **sample apps** (highly desired!)
- forums
- etc

Specifically for actually building Metro apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

I don't see many sample apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript out there..

To start things off, I have the obvious ones:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx
- http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=win8-intro

Comment: Seriously?  Almost all the resources out there are for JS instead of XAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For samples, you can start with http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/.

Note that you can narrow down your search criteria by selecting the desired language (this is present on the left pane).

For high level concepts and tutorials:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps

Javascript language reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/d1et7k7c.aspx

Windows programming (UI) with Javascript:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211669.aspx

Using WinJS controls (appbars etc.) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx

HTML & CSS
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229576.aspx

Note that not all samples work correctly. They have several runtime issues, the most common one being that a call to "WinJS.ProcessAll" is missing (this is required for most of the winJS controls). Second one is that references to required JS files are missing. I will recommend starting with the 'quick start' link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. 12 of the 17 chapters of the free ebook [Programming Windows 8 Apps
   with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/08/20/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript-second-preview.aspx) from MS Press are available for
   previewing. The complete book will be released on 26th Oct, 2012
2. [The PDF version of the Apress book Metro Revealed: Building Windows
   8 Apps with HTML5 and JavaScript by Adam Freeman is available as a
   free download from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/2/6529A101-DE4A-463A-8E33-F53A9826F010/apress-metro-revealed-freeman.pdf)
3. [Jeff Brand has written a nice article series on building a Metro-style HTML/JavaScript app on Windows 8](http://slickthought.net/post/2012/07/25/Windows-8-and-HTMLe28093Part-1-Simple-Example.aspx). The articles are short, simple & well-written. The content is also available in video format.